# Advantage of symlinks over Windows style shortcuts

Tags: windows, symlink

When I mainly used Windows, to make a shortcut, I could use a regular file detailing where it linked to, with the extension .lnk or .url

Now, on Linux, I mainly use symbolic links, which are a filesystem-specific feature.  Linux doesn't seem to have much support for file-based shortcuts, and Windows doesn't seem to have much support for symlinks.

I can see the advantage to using file based shortcuts (Can be used on any file system).

My question is, Why does linux use symlinks over file-based shortcuts, and on linux, how can I create shortcuts on file systems which don't support symlinks (eg FAT32)?

Comment: you should look up NTFS junction links.

Comment: also, I've never heard of a GNU/Linux filesystem that doesn't do symlinks. if you're using FAT my advice would be to get a better filesystem (I realize this is cheeky and useless, but it's true).

Comment: Most flash drives and sd cards are formatted with fat32 or vfat/fat64.  Also, that was just an example.

Also, a common filesystem is useful for transferring files between operating systems.

Comment: I know. FAT is a pretty terrible filesystem, but I realize it's useful - it was a joke.

Comment: Just to get your facts straight: Windows does support symlinks, NTFS supports symlinks and windows even ships with commands to create symlinks by default.

Comment: @Marco true. But the question is: "how can one create shortcuts on file systems which don't support symlinks".

Comment: @pepoluan There is no standard defining what a “shortcut” is and there is no need for it, since all modern operating systems and all modern file systems understand symlinks. Since there is no such standard which would allow different operating systems to understand each other's “shortcuts” the answer is: One cannot.

Comment: I just plugged an `ntfs` `usb` device into by Debian Gnu/Linux PC. I then created a sym-link on the device, it just worked. (the only fat only devices that I have are my camera, and radio)

Comment: To do symbolic links on file-systems that do not support them, you could try union-filesystems (overlay one on top of another), or file-system extensions. e.g. Rockridge adds Unix like extensions to ISO 9660 file-system.

Answer (score 1):

Symlinks are used because of two reasons:

1. It barely uses space on the hard disk. On filesystems where the metadata are reserved during creation (e.g., the ext2/3/4 family), symlinks is wholly contained as an `inode` in the filesystem metadata table.
2. It's completely transparent. See explanation below:

Let's say I in `/etc` I created a symlink `varlink` pointing to `/var`. With symlinks, I can do `cd /etc/varlink/lib`. If I then do an `ls`, I would see the contents of `/var/lib` (that is, the "`/etc/varlink`" part is 'replaced' with "`/var`"). I can go deeper to `/etc/varlink/lib/dbus`, in which I will see the contents of `/var/lib/dbus`. Yet, even though what I'm seeing is actually the contents of the latter, the `$CWD` (Current Working Directory) is still the former.

Similarly when symlinks are against files. Let's say that `/etc/fstab` is a symlink to `/opt/fstab`. I can do all operation against `/etc/fstab` (e.g., `cat` the contents, or perform `sed` against its contents) without having to first decode it to find the actual file it's symlinking to. The filesystem behind the scenes will take care of I/O redirection to the actual file.

---

And the answer to the second question: I don't think that is possible at all. At least, not via the shell.

Within a GUI, however, it is *possible* to have a program handle Windows' ".lnk" files, to redirect the file browser to somewhere else. But I'm not sure if such program is ever made.

Comment: You haven't answered the second part - Is it possible (and how) to use shortcuts on filesystems without symlink support on linux?

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: It is surely possible to implement “shortcuts” in an application, e.g. the shell. But symlinks are supported by the *operating system*, meaning no changes to any application have to be made to support symlinks. It's not at all related to having a GUI or not. To be able to compete with symlinks it would have to be implemented in the kernel (e.g. as a module) to be transparent to applications. But what problem would that solve that hasn't been solved already?

Comment: Erm, no. If transparent support for microsoft style links were implemented in Linux, the logic would sit in the filesystem code, not in the kernel. If you really need the capability then have a look at FUSE

Answer (score 0):

Advantages of sym-links:

1. transparency: Only management software has to know of the existence of sym-links. They just work. Shortcuts only work if the software trying to open them knows that they are a short cut. Syn-links work for all software, including legacy software.
2. chain-able: A sym-link will allow a link to a link to a link …
3. quicker: They are often stored in the inode (this may not always be true), making them quicker to look up.

Disadvantages:

1. Additional meta-information can be stored in a short-cut.
2. File-system support is not needed.
3. Instead of updating your file-system, you update every single other program in the system, this allows you to sell people the software that they already have, but with short-cut support, thus increasing revenue. (this advantage relies on your users not being free, you must have licensed the software under a proprietary licence.)