# Is it possible to create a soft link on my desktop which opens with the target path instead of the link's path?

Tags: linux, ln

I created a soft link with following command:

```
ln -s "/media/Eric/node/language/1-1.English/space@English/7-2 IELTS" ~/desktop/IELTS
```

On my desktop, when click to open the `IELTS` dir, the path is `/home/eric/Desktop/IELTS`.

I want the path to be the original path `/media/Eric/node/language/1-1.English/space@English/7-2 IELTS`, is that possible?

Comment: See if this is relevant -  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84175/create-a-symbolic-link-relative-to-the-current-directory

Comment: @cutrightjm Thanks for help, but it's not relevant much. In the question I did get the soft link works well, but the displaying directory path is the path of soft link, but not the path of original directory, if there is an option to display the original directory instead of the path of soft link then it would be convenient for some case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**short**: no, you cannot do it this way

**long**: a desktop launcher may work for you.

Unix-style symbolic links have only a *target* directory; there is no separate property for *source* directory.  You can read about symbolic links in

- [What is a symbolic link made from? Understanding the structure of symlinks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252561/what-is-a-symbolic-link-made-from-understanding-the-structure-of-symlinks/252587#252587)
- [Advantage of symlinks over Windows style shortcuts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90973/advantage-of-symlinks-over-windows-style-shortcuts)

As the question points out, the source directory is the desktop directory.

A comment mentions *[Create a symbolic link relative to the current directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84175/create-a-symbolic-link-relative-to-the-current-directory)*, but that is not relevant to the question.

The question refers to the behavior of shortcuts in Microsoft Windows.  With a desktop launcher, you can imitate this behavior (referring to [Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html), in the section [Recognized desktop entry keys](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html)):

> **`Exec`**
>   Program to execute, possibly with arguments. See the [Exec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html) key for details on how this key works. The **`Exec`** key is required if **`DBusActivatable`** is not set to true. Even if **`DBusActivatable`** is true, Exec should be specified for compatibility with implementations that do not understand **`DBusActivatable`**.
>
> **`Path`**
>   If entry is of type **`Application`**, the working directory to run the program in.

Unix symbolic links are **constants**, while [Windows shortcuts](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/16b71d26-7828-46ea-881a-66198cc88ab8/solved-dynamic-shortcuts-with-environment-variables?forum=w7itproui) can have (like Apollo Domain during the 1980s) embedded **variables**.  While the desktop specification goes into some detail regarding what is legal in [Exec](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html) (special variables), it lacks detail on where your environment variables might be used.  So implementations will differ.

Fortunately, the question as posed only requires constants, and launchers are the place to look for solutions.

Comment: Ok, I also found this link useful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/252587/78405

Answer (score 1):

A symbolic link will not do this.
However, a [link-type desktop file](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s06.html) will.

To try this for yourself,
create a desktop file called e.g. `link-to-7-2-IELTS.desktop`
with these contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Link to 7-2 IELTS
Type=Link
URL=file:///media/Eric/node/language/1-1.English/space%40English/7-2%20IELTS
Icon=folder
```

Note that the `@` sign and spaces in the path need to be [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to convert it into a proper [`file://` URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme). Some [file managers](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?t=96291) will [assist you](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=330204) in [generating these files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199973/is-it-possible-to-create-a-folder-shortcut-in-kubuntu/1266060#1266060).

Related:

- [Is there anyway to create a link that acts just like a shortcut?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253556/is-there-anyway-to-create-a-link-that-acts-just-like-a-shortcut)
- [Getting symbolic links to behave more like shortcuts in Windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281986/getting-symbolic-links-to-behave-more-like-shortcuts-in-windows)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/9450/is-it-possible-to-create-a-shortcut-link-instead-of-symbolic-link-to-a-folde
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028474/make-link-open-target-file-not-file-at-link-location
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131020/how-do-i-create-an-shortcut-to-a-foldernot-a-symlink-in-ubuntu-18-04-like-shor